# how to remove unwanted lines/noise in OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

i am developing an OCR app for android(building as java Application). i want to detect text from an image captured from camera and for pre-processing i am using OpenCV,but i am getting some extra lines which are being read as text,i have followed this approach:

1-RGB to GreyScale
2-Threshold
3-Gaussian Blur
4-Median Blur
5-Dilation 
6-Erosion

results are atleast better than before but still not getting the right results.
how can i remove this noise,what is a general sequence of filters like these that can be applied to any image to improve result for OCR.
i am new to OpenCV so please guide me through.
Thanks.

[old Image](http://i1161.photobucket.com/albums/q513/Asher_The-Exeptional/n_numb_zps31be28e5.jpg)

---

[Updated Image](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=713974225623)

---

from the above image i am able to find result from no 3,but only when all contours are drawn which is somthing that i dont want as there is noise also.what am i missing here.dont know what to do further.
Revised Code:

```
package simple_contours;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat src_img,src_grey,src_blur,src_thresh,src_dilate,dest_img; 
        src_img=Highgui.imread("n_num.jpg",Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


        src_grey=new Mat(src_img.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        src_blur=new Mat(src_img.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        src_thresh=new Mat(src_img.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        src_dilate=new Mat(src_img.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        dest_img=Mat.zeros(640,480, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Core.bitwise_not(dest_img, dest_img);
        Highgui.imwrite("dest.jpg", dest_img);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(src_img, src_grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src_grey, src_blur, new Size(3, 3), 0);
        Imgproc.threshold(src_blur, src_thresh, 80, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        Imgproc.dilate(src_thresh, src_dilate, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2, 2)));

        Highgui.imwrite("Threshold.jpg", src_thresh);
        Highgui.imwrite("Dilate.jpg", src_dilate);




          List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();  
          Mat heirarchy= new Mat();
          Point shift=new Point(150,0);
          Imgproc.findContours(src_dilate, contours,heirarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,shift);
          double[] cont_area =new double[contours.size()]; 

             for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++)
             { 
                Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
                cont_area[i]=Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

                System.out.println("Hight: "+rect.height);
                System.out.println("WIDTH: "+rect.width);
                System.out.println("AREA: "+cont_area[i]);
              //System.out.println(rect.x +","+rect.y+","+rect.height+","+rect.width);

                  Core.rectangle(src_img, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(0,0,255));
                  Imgproc.drawContours(dest_img, contours, i, new Scalar(0,0,0),-1,8,heirarchy,2,shift);
                  Core.rectangle(dest_img, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(0,255,0));
         }

             Highgui.imwrite("Final.jpg", dest_img);
             Highgui.imwrite("Original.jpg", src_img);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try Eroding the image (experiment with size of kernel) and then Dial ate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will only be able to go so far with the erode/dilate options. The issue is that the noise is a little more than just noise but contains artefacts that are not necessarily that dissimilar to some of the characters that you are trying to detect.

I would suggest that the solution will need to involve detecting contours in your image. First you should prepare the image to make it more manageable for the contouring process.

I've used the following sequence in the past:

- Gaussian Blur
- adaptiveThreshold
- negativeImage
- dilate

Now you can findContours. This should pick out the letters and the undesirable artefacts. You then need to eliminate artefacts, which you might need a number of strategies such as:

- work out the area of the bounding box and eliminate those with areas too small to be letters
- check width of the bounding box versus height: eliminate those with heights that are too small

there could be more sophisticated approaches such as trying to find the axis that runs through the middle of the larger contours, that would give you the position and direction of the characters (say as a rotated Rect); you could use that information to ignore all other pixels not in region.

Sorry it's not a simple solution but it is a complex problem so you might need to experiment a bit and build up multiple strategies to remove unwanted artefacts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i will follow what you mentioned and will get back with any progress.

Comment: I have found contours,but can't seems to draw them properly.could you please take a look at the Updated Image to understand my problem. @timegalore

Comment: The updated images look good; you have correctly bounded each letter with a box so you can then eliminate the undesirable ones. When you say the contours are not drawing properly - in what way? At the moment you draw them in black so they may not show up well as the text is black.

Comment: the problem is findcontour is detecting O and 4 as two different contours not as 1.you can see in image.this may be because of mode as CV_RETR_TREE,thickness -1(for CV_FILLED),and -1(for contourIdx) which draws all contours including noise.if I select i instead of -1,it draws selected contours but draws 0 and 4 filled.may be because O have 2 contours and does not draw the inner contour.i want to draw similar sized contours and the contours like O 4 which have holes in them should be read as single contour.i hope you get what i want to say

Comment: Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL is likely to be the best as that retrieves only the outer contour. I've not used the CV_FILLED option - I always specify a thickness. Is number 2 in the updated image not the effect you want? You can eliminate the smaller noisy bits by calculating their area.

Comment: cv_filled will let me fill the outlines of contours.while external will only give me external outline,leaving the inner shape of 4.which i dont want.there has to be some other work around to it.number 2 only gives the outer shape of 0 and 4 so i want shape like 3,but dont want inner contours and noise also.

Comment: Do you need to find all the contours for the letters and numbers. If you have a bounding box (as in 2) for the letters you could copy just those regions to a blank image thus removing anything that's outside of the boxes surrounding the lettering.

Comment: yes thats what i need,actually i have drawn these contours in a blank image,and as you are saying if i follow 2,i can select which contours i want to draw but i wont get the inner part of letter if i use retr_External.thats the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Eroding** the image *(experiment with size of kernel)* and then **Dilate** back to recover.

If the line/pixel noise(remaining noise or original) is very small, try **median blur** on it.
It should work, if not, please share your result to work on further.

Comment: I have done that like a hundred time but the problem is that i am not doing it for a specific image,different images give different result with specific settings.i have to find some other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using information from the Heirarchy,the 4th index value contains information about parent contour,so those contours which have -1 value should be drawn.this solved the filled contours problem. :)

Comment: Hi Asher, I'm not really sure what you mean here. If its possible can you explain a bit in detail